# React Basics Started Today

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, calculator

I started to learn to react today, and I'm trying to build a super simple calculator, but I'm not familiar with the syntax and basics of reacting yet. No matter how much I'm looking and reading, my code is like this :
import './App.css';

```
const plusaction = (a, b) => {
alert(a+b);
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="number" value={plusaction.a}></input>
      <input type="number" value={plusaction.b}></input>
      <button onClick={plusaction}>Result</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

As you can see, it was supposed to be a simple form plus action calculator, but the alert brought me "object undefined", Would you mind fixing my code and explaining what I did wrong? I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Happy, your question is answered (refering to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72338099/improving-caclculator-inside-react-progrem) ; do not forget to mark your question as aswered.

Answer (score 0):

First you must have a state to save data

after that, you must change your state with onChange function of input

after that, you must read your values from state

```
function App() { 
  const [state, setState] = useState({ a: 0, b: 0 });

  const plusaction = () => {
    alert(state.a + state.b);
  };


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="number" value={state.a} onChange={(e) => setState({ ...state, a: e.target.value })} />
      <input type="number" value={state.b} onChange={(e) => setState({ ...state, b: e.target.value })} />
      <button onClick={plusaction}>Result</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Ideally you want to want to store your input values in state. Here [I've initialised the `input` state as an object](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) which will later update with `a` and `b` properties containing the values of the inputs.
2. `plusAction` (or `handleAdd` as I've called it here) then just takes the `a` and `b` values from the `input` state and logs the sum to the console.
3. Give you input elements a `name` attribute so they can be identified easily.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

  // Initialise state
  const [ input, setInput ] = useState({});

  // Destructure the a and b properties from
  // the state and sum them
  function handleAdd() {
    const { a, b } = input;
    console.log(a + b);
  }

  // The onChange listener is attached to the
  // parent container so we need to check to see
  // if the changed element is an input
  function handleChange(e) {
    if (e.target.matches('input')) {

      // Destructure the name and value from the input
      const { name, value } = e.target;

      // Set the new input state by copying it, and
      // updating either the a or b property we get from
      // the name attribute, and then setting its value
      // Note: the type of the value from an input will
      // always be a string, so you need to coerce it to
      // a number first
      setInput({ ...input, [name]: Number(value) });
    }
  }

  // The input elements store the value of the
  // corresponding state property
  return (
    <div onChange={handleChange}>
      <input name="a" type="number" value={input.a} />
      <input name="b" type="number" value={input.b} />
      <button onClick={handleAdd}>Result</button>
    </div>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `useRef` to do this. It will more efficient than `useState` which will re-render your app each time your number change.

```
import { useRef } from "react";

function App() {
  const a = useRef(0);
  const b = useRef(0);

  const plusaction = () => {
    console.log(a.current.value);
    console.log(b.current.value);
    alert(parseInt(a.current.value) + parseInt(b.current.value));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="number" ref={a} />
      <input type="number" ref={b} />
      <button onClick={plusaction}>Result</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use controlled Input like this :

```
import {useState} from "react";
```

function App() {

```
const [firstVal,setFirstVal] = useState('');
const [secondVal,setSecondVal] = useState('');

const handleShowResult = ()=>{
    alert(parseInt(firstVal) + parseInt(secondVal))
}


return (
    <div className="App">
        <input type="number" value={firstVal} onChange={(e)=>setFirstVal(e.target.value)}></input>
        <input type="number" value={secondVal} onChange={(e)=>setSecondVal(e.target.value)}></input>
        <button onClick={handleShowResult}>Result</button>
    </div>
);
```

}

export default App;

hope its helpful

Answer (score 0):

You should use state to saving data.

```
import {useState} from "react";

function App() {
    const [firstNumber, setFirstNumber] = useState(0);
    const [secondNumber, setSecondNumber] = useState(0);

    const plusaction = () => {
        alert(firstNumber + secondNumber);
    };


    return (
        <div className="App">
            <input type="number" value={firstNumber} onChange={(e) => setFirstNumber(e.target.value)} />
            <input type="number" value={secondNumber} onChange={(e) => setSecondNumber(e.target.value)} />
            <button onClick={plusaction}>Result</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```